# Avoid jQuery code repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am making an animated progress bar. It's code is quite simple but the problem is that I can't figure out how to avoid repeating some jQuery code, you can see it in this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/N6c2q/

basically, this is what repeats:

```
$('.bar-value').animate({width: '+=1%'},50,function(){
    var percent = $('.bar-value').width() / $('.bar-value').parent().width()*100;
    var percInt = parseInt(percent);
    $('.progress').text(percInt+"%");
});
```

that just increases the width of the inner div (progress) by 1%, and increases .progress span number by 1. Is there any way to do what i'm trying to do without repeating that code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into the [jQuery UI progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/)?

Comment: You can just wrap that bit in a for loop.

Comment: @Luxelin haha yess but i like doing things by myself

Comment: See Darius's response below :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just give duration and amount you'd like to animate:

```
$('.bar-value').animate({width: '+=100%'},2000,function(){
    var percent = $('.bar-value').width() / $('.bar-value').parent().width()*100;
    var percInt = parseInt(percent);
    $('.progress').text(percInt+"%");
});
```

Comment: I really doubt that this is correct. If there's a `progress` for every `bar-value`, then this isn't right at all. He's already looping when he calls `.animate()`.

Comment: True statement cookie monster, I didn't look at that close enough! No need to loop at all. Just animate from 0-100% and set an appropriate duration.

Comment: hey , it worked, but, how can i ejecute a function after the loop finished?

Comment: @DariusHoule: I think you're right now. I couldn't tell what he meant by repeating, but it seems he just doesn't know how animate works.

Comment: ...however if he wanted to update the `.progress` with every "tick", that can be done with a separate callback function. I don't remember what it is off the top of my head though.

Comment: @cookiemonster Yeah, I was trying to figure out why he wasn't just animating the effect for a given time frame. Sort of defeated the point of animate…

Comment: ...ah, it seems that if you pass an `options` object that includes a `progress` callback, it'll be invoked for every individual change in the animation. http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options

Comment: ...you might also consider using `$(this)` instead of `$(".bar-value")` in the callback. It's an enormously less expensive operation.

Comment: @user3597089 you are already executing a function when the animation completes. The function you are passing into `animate` is the completion function.

Comment: @user3597089: Here's a fixed up version that builds on the changes Darius made. http://jsfiddle.net/N6c2q/4/

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion:

```
function showProgress(finish) {
    $('.bar-value').animate({
        width: '+=1%'
    }, 50, function () {
        var percent = $('.bar-value').width() / $('.bar-value').parent().width() * 100;
        var percInt = parseInt(percent);
        $('.progress').text(percInt + "%");

        if (percInt != 100) {
            showProgress(finish);
        } else {
            if (finish) finish();
        }
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N6c2q/2/)

**Edit:** fix

Comment: Why use recursion when you can do it more elegantly using iteration?

Comment: Recursion is more elegant to me.

Comment: Until you run out of memory.  Iteration is almost always better if you can use it.

Comment: If you're going to talk about elegance, format your code correctly.

Comment: **You are welcome.** Note that you can *re-indent* messy code using http://jsbeautifier.org or http://jsfiddle.net, and format it in an answer or question by selecting your code and then clicking in the **`{}`** icon in the formatting bar.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, that code is madness!!

So I would recommend you to use [jQuery UI progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#label)

Otherwise you can use a loop to do what you are trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/db306/N6c2q/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var percent = $('.bar-value').width() / $('.bar-value').parent().width()*100;
    $('.progress').text(percent+"%");

    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.loader').fadeIn(1200);
        $('button').attr('disabled','disabled');


        for (var i=0; i<100;i++){
            $('.bar-value').animate({width: '+=1%'},50,function(){
            var percent = $('.bar-value').width() / $('.bar-value').parent().width()*100;
            var percInt = parseInt(percent);
            $('.progress').text(percInt+"%");
        });
        }
    });
});
```